# How can I find on-chain data for NFT collections?

Tags: blockchain, nft

Seems that there are tons of NFTs being minted and sold every day but all current APIs are either expensive or require to be approved plus have limits. Is there any alternative where I can query and get real-time on chain data without breaking the bank or being limited?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bitquery to get real-time NFT data. This API provider offers a free plan.

Here is an example that shows how to get **NFT transfers**:
 https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/examples/nft/nft-transfer-api/

The same query can be used for the minting of NFT. Just check whenever the address is `null`.

You can also use **NFT Trades API** to get buy, sell, latest trades, and other data from major marketplaces:
https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/examples/nft/nft-trades-apI/

Answer (score 0):

NFTPort is launching their service for Solana as Beta, maybe you can try it out, for instance, in Go it would be:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

    url := "https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/solana/nfts"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "01854222-6888-468d-b8de-99ced004efe6")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

You can read the full doc at https://docs.nftport.xyz/docs/nftport/b3A6Njg1NTI0MDA-retrieve-all-solana-nf-ts